# Meaning of "thumb-sucking charges" in The Sellout by Paul Beatty

Tags: meaning, paul-beatty, the-sellout

I'm reading *The Sellout* by Paul Beatty. In this paragraph I can't understand the meaning of "**thumb-sucking charges**" in this paragraph:

> Ample bosoms first, she hops the rail, bogarts her way past the cops,
> and bolts toward me, **her thumb-sucking charges** clinging
> desperately to her “Don’t You See How Insanely Long, Soft, Shiny, and
> Expensive This Is? Motherfucker, YOU WILL Treat Me Like a Queen!” Toni
> Morrison signature model pashmina shawl trailing behind her like a
> cashmere kite tail.
>
> Now she’s in my face, mumbling calmly but incoherently about black
> pride, the slave ships, the three-fifths clause, Ronald Reagan, the
> poll tax, the March on Washington, the myth of the dropback
> quarterback, how even the white-robed horses of the Ku Klux Klan were
> racist, and, most emphatically, how the malleable minds of the
> ever-increasingly redundant “young black youth” must be protected. And
> lo, the mind of the little waterheaded boy with both arms wrapped
> about his teacher ’s hips, his face buried in her crotch, definitely
> needs a bodyguard, or at least a mental prophylactic. He comes up for
> air looking expectantly to me for an explanation as to why his teacher
> hates me so. Not getting one, the pupil returns to the warm moistness
> of his happy place, oblivious to the stereotype that black males don’t
> go down there.

Is it pointing out to the little boy in next paragraph?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A "charge" refers to, in this context, a person entrusted to another's care. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/charge) defines it like this:

> 3 b
> : a person or thing committed into the care of another
> played with her young *charges* at the day-care center

Young kids often suck their thumbs. It's a thing that [a very large percentage](https://www.webmd.com/parenting/features/9-ways-to-wean-a-child-off-thumb-sucking) of children do.

So yes, in this context, "thumb-sucking charges" refers to small children entrusted to the teacher's care.